# How do I differentiate between different keyboards?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I want to be able to differentiate between several keyboards for macro purposes, such that, for example, pressing the x key on one keyboard does something different than pressing the x key on a different keyboard.

I tried to search for videos of how to do this on youtube, but most of them were for windows.

I'm thinking that I would use a program that, when a key is detected, would execute an AutoKey script depending on the key which is pressed and the keyboard the stroke is coming from.

How can I do this?

Comment: This was talked about on a Ubuntu Podcast (UK) awhile back ([early-mid] 2018, if not [mid-late] 2017).  I was interested because I use a model M for my typing, but have a more modern one within reach for its media keys; it allowed me to code/use all keys on my second keyboard as macro keys; but I can't recall its method.   If you get no better suggestion, the answer was covered by Mark (as I recall) on Ubuntu Podcast.

Comment: I wasn't able to find it. Could you give me an link to it?